# Is it possible to skip past a login page to run Xamarin UI tests?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin UI Tests based on the `NUnit.Framework` to test my application. I currently have a Login page that makes a request to a online server to check user credentials. Is it possible to bypass this screen and get Xamarin UI Tests to start running a test on a specific page?

Comment: You don't seem to be doing a unit test but an integration test. You should either check the differences or better isolate the components.
In an unit test you must be able to mock services injected to your SUT

Comment: Thanks @JorgeeFG, from the other answers it appears I am doing a sort of in-between UI and Unit test. [ThomasL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65716690/13902576) below is closest to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to decide which kind or type of test you want to execute. Do you want to a behavior driven test or a unit test. The Xamarin UI-Test framework is intended to do behavior driven tests or user acceptance driven tests. To test the app as a whole and not separate parts like you do it at Unit-Tests.

If you want to use Xamarin UI-Test, my recommendation is to create a IAuthInterface and implement 2 classes for it. One which implements the real auth provider in combination with your data-interface and one you mock. It depends on your architecture if you want to include authentication and data-service.

```
public interface IAuthService
{
    Task<bool> Login(string user, string password);
}

public class MockService : IAuthService
{
    public Task<bool> Login(string user, string password)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
    }
}

public class DataService : IAuthService, IRepositoryService
{
   public Task<bool> Login(string user, string password)
    {
        //Do real authentication
    }
}
```

For the test you can register the Mock-implementation and build the APK to test.

Comment: This doesn't seem too overly complicated. Thanks for your in-depth explanation, has helped me find the re-engineering a little less daunting!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `Page Object Pattern`.

Each page in your app is a class in your test code. And page classes define methods for all the actions that can be taken on that page.

I use your LoginPage for example. You could use other pages directly.

```
[Test]
public void LogInTest()
{
    new LogInPage()
        .EnterCredentials("username", "password")
        .ConfirmLogIn();

    new HomePage();
}
```

For more details for the steps, you could check the link below. https://github.com/xamarin-automation-service/uitest-pop-example/wiki/POP-Implementation

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. I have seen that from my research, but wasn't sure if there was another way. Using the Page Object Pattern, I would need to re-write some of my implementation. Ideally, I would like to implement some form of mocking to simplify this whole process. I will have a look at [ThomasL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65716690/13902576) above.